# Type handler for ArrayList in myBatis

Tags: mybatis

I am Trying to write type handler for ArrayList but this is giving me errors can any one help me.

I want to store ArrayList as VARCHAR in DB  and retrieve it as ArrayList.

```
package com.someweb.typehandlers;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;
//@MappedTypes(java.util.ArrayList.class)

//@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR)
public class StringArrayListTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<ArrayList<String>> 
{
@Override
public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, ArrayList<String> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
        throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder(parameter.toString());
    ps.setString(i,str.substring(1,str.length()-1));

}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String str=rs.getString(columnName);

    ArrayList<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] rolesarray=str.split(",");
    for(String s:rolesarray)
    roles.add(s);

    return roles;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str=rs.getString(columnIndex);

    ArrayList<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] rolesarray=str.split(",");
    for(String s:rolesarray)
    roles.add(s);

    return roles;   }

@Override
public ArrayList<String> getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str=cs.getString(columnIndex);

    ArrayList<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] rolesarray=str.split(",");
    for(String s:rolesarray)
    roles.add(s);

    return roles;   }

}
```

I am new to myBatis . So some one help me i am not able to figure out how this can be accomplished

My dto class looks like this

```
package com.someweb.dto;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDTO implements Principal {

private int id;
private String username;

private String name;
private String password;
private String token;
private String email;
private boolean isAuthenticated;
private boolean is_active;

private List<String> role;
private String phone;
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean isAuthenticated() {
    return isAuthenticated;
}

public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) {
    this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
}

public List<String> getRole() {
    return role;
}



public void setRole(List<String> role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
     this.role.add(role);
}
 public void addRole(String role)
 {
     if(role==null) this.role=new ArrayList<String>();
     this.role.add(role);

 }

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean isIs_active() {
    return is_active;
}

public void setIs_active(boolean is_active) {
    this.is_active = is_active;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

my mapper file code is like this

```
    <resultMap id="userResultMap" type="com.someweb.dto.UserDTO">
  <id property="id" column="id" />
  <result property="username" column="username"/>
  <result property="password" column="password"/>
  <result property="email" column="email"/>
 <result property="phone" column="phone"/>
 <result property="is_active" column="is_active"/>
  <collection property="role" ofType="java.lang.String" >
        <result column="role" />
    </collection>

</resultMap>
<insert id="insertUser" useGeneratedKeys="true"
    keyProperty="id">
  insert into tblusers(username,password,email,phone,role,is_active) 
  values(#{username},#{password},#{email},#{phone},#{role,typeHandler=com.someweb.typehandlers.StringArrayListTypeHandler},#{is_active})
</insert>
```

now the insertion executes . But when retrieving the data to DTO the entire the role field is been fetched as single string in ArrayList .

And if remove the typeHandler attribute i am getting errors

```
Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

Comment: add raised exception in your question

Comment: Beware: as I already said in your other question, if you annotate the type handler `@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR)`, it will be used by default to map column type Varchar, for any column of any query of your app, this is unlikely what you want.

Comment: I would replace `ArrayList` with `List` (best practice anyway). Try remove annotation and reference in `typeHandler` section on Mybatis config instead as I have noticed strange behaviors with those annotation.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You need at least specify more precisely what error you get and the example code that uses or is supposed to use this handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

Collection is used to fetch many side of one-to-many relation ship So it always returns Collection of Objects from multiple records

In my case i need ArrayList from single cell of record so . i have to remove `<collection>` tag 
and by just using `<result>` tag as shown below code works

```
<result property="role" column="role" javaType="java.util.ArrayList"
        jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="com.greenflight.typehandlers.StringArrayListTypeHandler" />
```